# Can't focus on input element inside jQuery UI menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jQuery UI menu for something other than a navigation menu. Its very close to what I want, which is a simple dropdown widget, and I don't want to grab yet another plugin for this simple feature.

I am trying to put an input field in the menu item, but I am unable to click on it. Here is a simple (clumsy) example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmba79z8/

```
$('#m').menu({
   menus: '.sub',
   items: '.filter',
   position: {
     my: 'left top',
     at: "left bottom"
   },
   role: null,
 });
```

Is there a way to make the input field accessible?

Comment: Interesting - reviewing your fiddle and investigating.

Comment: So far I have found nothing that prevents the `input` from being used. When I right-click the field, I can gain focus. I just cannot left-click into the field. I suspect this is due to it having been hidden when collapsed and then shown when expanded.

Comment: Adding a event bound to click that forces focus has a side-effect of the menu being collapsed. I am thinking there is some level of focus disruption happening. Might need to hide the `.sub` and then reveal it when `menuitem` is clicked versus exposing it with `menus` option.

Comment: Even with all options stripped out: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lmba79z8/6/ It's still not allowing focus. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish in more detail? Thinking the fields could be hidden off the page and shown when the menu item is clicked.

Comment: @Twisty, thanks for looking at this. I am trying to use the menu widget to create dropdowns that are much like Zurb Foundation dropdowns, rather than an actual menu. I ended up rolling my own solution that took 20 minutes compared to the hours I spent messing with the jquery menu.

Comment: Cool. I was going to suggest using accordion.

Comment: Yea, I was just using the wrong tool for the job. But I'm still curious what attribute/styling or whatever would prevent an input from being usable. I'll leave this up in case anyone stumbles across it and knows the answer.